# Is fedora advisable to install as dual boot in ASUS ROG Strix G

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, software-rec, asus

I Have Asus ROG Strix G laptop. Planning to install Linux (Fedora) as dual boot. Linux will be the primary OS.

Planning to use it for Data science and ML learning too.

Is it advisable to do without impacting laptop as it has NVIDIA graphics cards and other stuffs which looks only supported in windows

Also, which is the best spin in case opting for Fedora for the machine?

Comment: I think it will just install fedora well ; as I have a debian on an older model of ASUS ROG whith all devices supported .

Comment: my concern is that it should work well with graphics card(NVIDIA) as i couldnt find any official driver release from nvidia for linux.

Comment: I found one, go to nvidia.com > drivers (https://www.nvidia.fr/Download/index.aspx?lang=en), select the series for your graphics card, RTX 40 (notebook) for a 4080 or 4090 ...

Answer (score 0):

If it has intel graphics on the CPU, boot to linux and use the prime-select tool to switch to the intel graphics card.

sudo prime-select intel

NVIDIA and linux are not very friendly to each other.

Comment: Then will it make NVIDIA's usage void ??

Mainly when it comes to its need in high intensity works like data science models or ML algorithms which i plan to learn using this

Comment: NVIDIA wont break linux, you just might have some glitchy visual effects if you use a lightweight DM. Gnome DM and other "big ones" should run fine with NVIDIA.

Comment: Oh! okay thanks , let me try installing then :)

hope i'll be able to use NVIDIA like in windows at-least upto some benchmark